# display the same image in a loop while retrieving data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, image, loops

I'm looking for a solution to the following.

I have certain data stored in a mysql table. As for now I am able to retrieve the data and display it on a page. But now I would like to add a small png to one specific part of the data. One variable is a time period, like '25-28 of March', this continually changes. But I would like to add a calendar icon in front of this. How can I best proceed. I've been looking at this for hours now.

This is my php code to display the data on the page (write_to_site.php):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h3> " . $row["conferentie"] . "</h3><p>" . HERE THE ICON $row["datums"] . "</p><p>" . $row["locatie"] . "</p><hr>";
    }
```

I use php include write_to_site.php on the page where I want this displayed.

It should look something like this (this is only html):
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LrsJ.png)

So the icon should always be the same, so there is no need to store it in de database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this `"</h3><p>" . HERE THE ICON` to `"</h3><p><img src=\"myIcon.png\" />" .`

Comment: Yep! Thanks that worked! :D I'm getting pretty confused by the order of forward and backward slashes and single and double quotation marks in this part of php.